# how do i change an old project I had so it can use ARC?

Tags: ios, xcode, automatic-ref-counting

I started an old project in an xcode that did not support ARC, how can I change my project into using ARC and how do I know what to remove from the project?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In Xcode, Edit => Refactor => Convert to Objective-C ARC... and follow the instructions.

Comment: I have a project that has RestKit 0.10.0 inside and the RestKit is giving me a lot of errors, would it work to only convert my project to ARC and leave the RestKit like that or will it throw errors?

Comment: Yes, you can mix ARC and non-ARC code. In the target Build Phases, under Compile Sources, set the compiler flag to `-fno-objc-arc` on non-ARC .m files.